# Drag and Drop from JTable to JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable, jlayeredpane

How to create Drag and drop between **JTable** and **JLayeredPane**.

Does anyone have any ideas how to implement this?

**I need transfer object by Drag and drop between JTable and JLayeredPane**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a few things at minimum to get this to work:

- Call `setDragEnabled(true)` on your `JTable` instance
- Set the `JTable`s and `JLayeredPane`s [`DropTarget`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DropTarget.html)
- Create a draggable `Component` to add to the `JLayeredPane`

---

To set a `Component`s `DropTarget`, call the `setDropTarget(DropTarget d)` method and pass an anonymous inner class as the argument. Code that drops the [`Transferable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html)s data into the `Component` should be located in the `drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde)` method.

The below snippet shows how to receive a `Transferable` and insert it into the row of a `JTable` where the drop was initiated:

```
table.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {

    @Override
    public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
        try {
            // get row to put new item in
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(dtde.getLocation());
            // inserting row:
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(
                    //if the row wasn't found, add it to the end of the JTable
                    row == -1 ? table.getRowCount() : row,
                    // pass string flavor of transferable data as row data parameter
                    new Object[] {dtde.getTransferable()
                                .getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)});
        } catch(UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

This below snippet again receives a `Transferable` but instead adds it to the end of a `JLayeredPane`. Note that components are added to the end of the `JLayeredPane` because I assign a `BoxLayout(SwingConstants.VERTICAL)` to it.

```
layeredPane.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {

    @Override
    public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
        try {
            // create draggable label to add to layered pane 
            // creating this class will be explained next
            final DraggableLabel label = new DraggableLabel(
                    (String) dtde.getTransferable()
                    .getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));

            // add label to layered pane
            layeredPane.add(label, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
            layeredPane.revalidate();
            layeredPane.repaint();
        } catch(UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});
```

---

To create a draggable `Component` (In this example a `JLabel`), you must:

- Create a new class that `extends` `JLabel` and `implements` [`DragGestureListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DragGestureListener.html) and [`DragSourceListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DragSourceListener.html)
- Override all the necessary methods
- In the constructor:

  - Create a new [`DragSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DragSource.html)
  - Create a [`DragGestureRecognizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DragGestureRecognizer.html) and assign it to `this` the `JLabel` subclass and `this` the `DragGestureListener`
- Start a drag using the `DragSource` in the `dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent evt)` method

```
class DraggableLabel extends JLabel implements DragGestureListener, DragSourceListener {

    private DragSource dragSource;

    DraggableLabel(String text) {
        super(text);

        // create the drag source
        dragSource = new DragSource();
        // assign this component a DragGestureRecognizer
        dragSource.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(
                this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this);

        // for contrast with other items in layered pane
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
    }

    @Override
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent evt) {
        dragSource.startDrag(
                evt, //trigger event
                DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop, // icon
                new StringSelection(getText()), // transferable data
                this); // this the DragSourceListener
    }

    @Override
    public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {}

    @Override
    public void dragOver(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {}

    @Override
    public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent evt) {}

    @Override
    public void dropActionChanged(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {}

    @Override
    public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent evt) {}

}
```

---

Full working example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureListener;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSource;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSourceListener;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

class DragDropExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JLabel Text Example");

            final JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(
                    new Object[][] {
                            {"Item 1"},
                            {"Item 2"},
                            {"Item 3"},
                            {"Item 4"},
                            {"Item 5"}},
                    new String[] {"Column Name"}));
            table.setDragEnabled(true);
            table.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {

                @Override
                public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                    try {
                        // get row to put new item in
                        int row = table.rowAtPoint(dtde.getLocation());
                        // inserting row:
                        ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(
                                //if the row wasn't found, add it to the end of the JTable
                                row == -1 ? table.getRowCount() : row,
                                // pass string flavor of transferable data as row data parameter
                                new Object[] {dtde.getTransferable()
                                        .getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)});
                    } catch(UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            final JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane() {

                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(200, 300);
                }

            };
            layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            layeredPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(layeredPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            layeredPane.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {

                @Override
                public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                    try {
                        // create draggable label to add to layered pane
                        // creating this class will be explained next
                        final DraggableLabel label = new DraggableLabel(
                                (String) dtde.getTransferable()
                                        .getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));

                        // add label to layered pane
                        layeredPane.add(label, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                        layeredPane.revalidate();
                        layeredPane.repaint();
                    } catch(UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });

            frame.getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.WEST);
            frame.getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    static class DraggableLabel extends JLabel implements DragGestureListener, DragSourceListener {

        private DragSource dragSource;

        DraggableLabel(String text) {
            super(text);

            // create the drag source
            dragSource = new DragSource();
            // assign this component a DragGestureRecognizer
            dragSource.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(
                    this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this);

            // for contrast with other items
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        }

        @Override
        public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent evt) {
            dragSource.startDrag(
                    evt, //trigger event
                    DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop,
                    new StringSelection(getText()),
                    this);
        }

        @Override
        public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {}

        @Override
        public void dragOver(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {}

        @Override
        public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent evt) {}

        @Override
        public void dropActionChanged(DragSourceDragEvent evt) {}

        @Override
        public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent evt) {}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DropTarget dt = new DropTarget(Droptargetobject, new DropTargetAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
            //executed if mouse with items enters object
        }

        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
            //executed if you drop the item
        }
});
```

and to implement the drag use a `java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent;`.
i hope you understand what i mean

imports i used:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetAdapter;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
```

Comment: I have no `DropTargetAdapter class` , I'm getting errors

Comment: added imports to answer

Comment: Ok, errors have gone away. As I understand, I should put this code to the `JTable mouseDragged` listener (mousemotionListener) ?

Comment: I mean how to use `DropTarget dt` and where I should it put it ?

Comment: the droptarget code should come after the jlayered pane and the "Droptargetobject" is your jlayeredpane, since you want to be able to drop items on it.

Comment: Ok, explain please how to implement the **drag**, I don't understand. I'm using `JTable.addMouseMotionListener()`, that NetBeans generate for drag mouse event ?

Comment: i think i misunderstood something about mousemotionlistener in first place. better use the draggesture from java.awt.dnd. i cannot help you with the drag much since i never used it

Comment: it does help you with the drop. maybe ill try to get the drag working as well

Comment: Yes, may be you are right, but I do not see a complete picture, and I can't imagine how to implement that, and create working example.
**Actually I need transfer object by Drag and drop between JTable and JLayeredPane.**
Anyway, thank you for your try.